# In my Statement of Purpose (SOP), is it best to write about my specific area of interest, or to broaden my options?

Tags: graduate-admissions, advisor, computer-science, statement-of-purpose

I am currently a 4th year CS undergrad student.

If I tailor my Statement of Purpose (SOP) around my research interests (which are related to the research project I am working on with my professor), I feel like I may be limiting myself to professors who are in my field of interest, but may not have any funding, or may not accept any PhD students. Is this detrimental?

Answer (score 0):

If you seem to absolutely rule out all other options, then yes, it could hurt you since it lessens the likelihood of finding an advisor.

However, it is good to narrow the field somewhat (languages, algorithms, AI,..., whatever). And it is good to say that you have some specific interest and experience with that.

So, be flexible, but focused.

In my own case (math), I'd have been happy in either Topology or Classical Analysis and had some insight in both. My dissertation was the latter.